# Cut-distance between two Erdos-Renyi random graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider two Erdos-Renyi random graphs $G_1, G_2$ on $n$ nodes, with the edges in each graph generated independently at random with probability $1/2$.  My question is about the cut-distance between these two graphs.  Recall that the cut-distance is the maximum over all cuts of the difference between the cut values of the two graphs.  Using a standard Chernoff bound argument for each cut, followed by a union bound to maximize over all cuts, I get that the cut-distance between $G_1,G_2$ is $O(n^{3/2})$ with large probability.  Is this the tightest bound one can show?  I'm wondering if it is possible to get this distance down to $O(n)$?